# Finding consecutive weeks person appears in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I need to find how many consecutive weeks a person appears in a table, starting with the current week.

The table has an ID and an insert date.  If a person is inserted into the table, I need to calculate if they were there the prior week and if so how many consecutive weeks prior to that.

I've tried a few gap-island techniques that I've searched, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

EDIT
SQL Server 2012

```
ID-PK (int)
PersonID (int)
CourseNumber (varchar(15))
Term (char(5))
InsertDate (datetime)

Sample Data
250029 - 507 - 541 - Q2 - 2016-11-27
250028 - 507 - 541 - Q2 - 2016-11-20
250027 - 507 - 541 - Q2 - 2016-11-13
250027 - 507 - 541 - Q2 - 2016-10-13
```

So in the example with this data, I would like to retrieve "3" as the answer since that person appeared in the table for three consecutive weeks prior to the break between 10/13/2016 and 11/13/2016.

Thanks

Comment: A couple of items.  1) Which RDMS  2) Sample Data and desired results would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Possible way would be to add a RowID (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) partitioned by WeekNumber and PersonName.

Then join result back onto it's self where PersonName = PersonName and RID = RID + 1. Then count results by PersonName .

This will give you an answer for people who worked consecutive weeks but not more than 2. Would need data to get a fully working script.